# Can I use a lambda expression here (selecting records from a numpy.core.records.recarray)?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following code snippet, which loads data from a CSV file into a numpy.core.records.recarray:

```
r = mlab.csv2rec(datafile, delimiter=',', names=('dt', 'val'))
data = zip(date2num(r['dt']),r['val']) # Need to filter for records lying between two dates here ...
```

I want to only 'zip' records that have dates falling bewteen (say) '2000-01-01' and 2000-03-01'

I understand the concept of lambda functions - but I haven't used them before. It would be cool if I could use a lambda to filter the records between the required dates (like in pseudocode below):

```
data = zip(lambda: date2num(r['dt']),r['val'] if r['dt'] > '2000-01-01' and r['dt'] < '2000-03-01' )
```

What is the Pythonic way to extract a subset of data from the rec.array, based on specified indixes (i.e. dates)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda (often combined with map or filter) is generally a less pythonic and clear solution to the same problem that [list comprehensions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY) and its cousins solve.

```
[dt, val for dt, val in zip(date2num(r['dt'], r['val'])) if '2000-01-01' < r['dt'] < '2000-03-01']
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using numpy, you don't need lambda function to do this kind of things.

Here is an example, you can campare array with value as r["dt"] >= date(2000,1,1), This will get a bool array, and use "&" operator, you can calculate bitwise and of two bool array. Finally, use a bool array as the index, you can get the values corresponding to True.

```
import pylab as pl
import StringIO
from datetime import date
data = """2000-01-01,3
1999-04-01,5
2000-01-11,4
2000-02-21,7
2000-08-12,8
"""

r = pl.csv2rec(StringIO.StringIO(data), delimiter=",", names=("dt","val"))
mask = (r["dt"] >= date(2000,1,1)) & (r["dt"] <= date(2000,3,1))

r2 = r[mask]

print zip(pl.date2num(r2["dt"]), r2["val"])
```

Comment: +1 for the alternative approach. Reminds me a bit of R ... I wonder which of the two answers is more effecient?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli If performance is really important to you, check out the timeit module http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html - it allows you to easily test two alternative methods.